# ECS task stuck in PENDING state

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-app-mesh

I am trying out AWS App-Mesh, I have pushed an image to ECR which starts a web server on 8080 port, and created an ECS service for it. I have been following this guide just to try out the service https://docs.aws.amazon.com/app-mesh/latest/userguide/getting-started-ecs.html . When I get to the part where I update my service with enabled AppMesh, my task gets stuck in the PENDING state and envoy task is unhealthy (screenshot attached)

I am using

> 840364872350.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/aws-appmesh-envoy:v1.21.1.2-prod

as envoy image

[image]

To be honest I don't really understand how this works and I want to know if I can debug this somehow to understand the problem. Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

With ECS AppMesh Integration, a **ContainerDependency**(container startup order) is added to the application container to only start if **envoy** is healthy. See images below:

[Application Container with Container Ordering (View container)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzYxS.png)

[Application Container with Container Ordering (Edit task/container)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfFlc.png)

In order to find out why **envoy** container is UNHEALTHY I would suggest enabling logging on the **envoy** container. In my scenario the envoy container couldn't retrieve EC2 Task Metadata (see below snippet) and hence the envoy container was UNHEALTHY in my case, so the ECS task would remain in *pending* indefinitely.

```
[error][aws] [source/extensions/common/aws/credentials_provider_impl.cc:118] Could not retrieve credentials listing from the EC2MetadataService
```

After adding the necessary permission in the ECS Task Role, the issue was resolved, as the **envoy** container was healthy and the application container can start as well. Hope the above helps.